# jQuery global variable with getScript

Tags: jquery, global-variables, getscript

I have this myObject decalred in foo.js, and modifed in bar.js.

And I tried to get the result when getScript is done. However it seems myObject is not a global variable if it is decalred inside jQuery.

Can someone please explain this to me?

**foo.js**

```
/*
    // this works fine, but I want to decalre it inside jQuery
    var myObject = {
        str: "hello world",
        num: "123"
    };
*/

$(function() {

    // this makes myObject NOT a global valriable
    var myObject = {
        str: "hello world",
        num: "123"
    };

    alert(myObject.str + " " + myObject.num);

    $.getScript("bar.js", function() {
        alert(myObject.str + " " + myObject.num);
    });
});
```

**bar.js**

```
$(function() {
    myObject = {
        str: "new string",
        num: "999"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks Arun, but this works... `window`.myObject

```
$(function() {

    // global variable defined inside function
    window.myObject = {
        str: "hello world",
        num: "123"
    };

    // ...
});
```

Comment: that is the same as declaring it outside

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes they have the same scope but as I stated in my question... I want the variable to be **declared inside** jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared the variable inside a function, it is local to the function. What you can do is declare the variable outside but assign the value inside the jQuery ready handler

**foo.js**

```
/*
    // this works fine, but I want to decalre it inside jQuery
    var myObject = {
        str: "hello world",
        num: "123"
    };
*/

var myObject;
$(function() {

    // this makes myObject NOT a global valriable
    myObject = {
        str: "hello world",
        num: "123"
    };

    alert(myObject.str + " " + myObject.num);

    $.getScript("bar.js", function() {
        alert(myObject.str + " " + myObject.num);
    });
});
```

**bar.js**

```
$(function() {
    myObject = {
        str: "new string",
        num: "999"
    };
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qGXvPgDiVpM1dXhtM5rJ?p=preview)

Comment: So...the variables inside the 2 jQuery functions (from 2 js files in my example) are NOT in the same scope, is that right?

Comment: @user1643156 yes... depending on how the variable is declared